# what does 'admin/build/modules' mean?

Tags: routes

I'm a total newbie to Drupal so I'm starting by trying to follow some tutorials. One says to enable a module at **admin/build/modules** but I have no idea what this means. I assume this is a path through menus, but my admin menu item has no build submenu.

[image: Menu at top of drupal installation]

Which is the correct path?

Comment: which tutorial did you follow? The usual page for modules is at /admin/modules and the page for installing additional ones at /admin/modules/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7 modules are enabled at the path 'admin/modules'.
In Drupal 6 the path is 'admin/build/modules'.

Comment: But when I go to admin/modules there is nothing like profile to enable.  The module I am looking for is supposed to be 'The core Profile module (enable in admin/build/modules)'.  I don't see it and can't find it when I try to search.   Anyway, thanks for the info, now its a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

To enable a module go to `admin/modules`, then it show you list of enabled/disabled modules and you can enable any of them. what else do you want to know?